# Excel Column Formula with Conditional Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a summary table like this:

```
Total Pay | Amount Unpaid | Total Left
```

It is based on a table with the following format:

```
Date | Hours | Pay    | Paid
...  | 5     | 100.00 | Yes
...  | 4     | 80.00  | No
...  | 6     | 120.00 | Yes
```

I am trying to create a formula that will fill in the `Amount Unpaid` column.

I have this so far which gives me the error: 'Error in Value':

```
=SUM(IF(Sunshine!E5:E6,Sunshine!D5:D6,0))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `SUMIF` function:

```
=SUMIF (E2:E5, "No", D2:D5)
```

This will add all values in D2:D5, but only if the corresponding row in E2:E5 equals "No".